# Menger's theorem via matroids

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-optimization, matroid-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an oriented graph, $Y\subset V$ be some fixed set of its vertices. Call $A\subset V$ *independent* if there exist $|A|$ vertex-disjoint paths starting in $A$ and ending in $Y$. It is not hard to prove this independence system is actually a matroid. Indeed, matroids arising in this way are called [gammoids](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Gammoid).

Menger's theorem (in Goering's form, I think) states that the rank function of this matroid is given by

$r(A)=$the minimum number vertices which may be deleted so that no path from $A$ to $Y$ remains.

Is there any matroid interpretation, or matroids-assisted proof of this?

I saw some papers in which both Menger's theorem and matroids appear in the title, but on the first glance they deal with usual cycles/cuts graph matroids.

Comment: is such a connection not there in Schrijver's volume 2?

Comment: as i suspected, page 720 of Schrijver's book cites Tutte's proof of Menger's theorem for matroids (see http://books.google.com/books?id=mqGeSQ6dJycC&lpg=PA720&ots=xOOLFZdjNi&dq=menger's%20theorem%20for%20matroids&pg=PA720#v=onepage&q=menger's%20theorem%20for%20matroids&f=false)

Comment: Thanks, Suvrit! The book does not open, but maybe it is the same theorem which Tony cites below?

Comment: Yeah, somehow the link does not open; but if you search for "menger theorem matroids" on books.google.com, it shows you Schrijver's book, for which it shows page 720 (though sometimes it refuses to show the content); but yes, Tony is citing the same result!

Comment: @Suvrit: it looks like googlebooks changed the rules, and now we not from the States have no right to see many books, including this one(

Answer (score 20):

There is indeed a Menger's theorem for matroids first proven by Tutte.  The reference is

> Tutte, W. T., Menger’s theorem for matroids, Journal of Research of the National
>   Bureau of Standards—B. Mathematics and Mathematical Physics, 69B (1965), 49–53.

A copy of the paper can be found [here](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/69B/jresv69Bn1-2p49_A1b.pdf).

This theorem is nowadays called *Tutte's linking theorem,* and it is sad that it is not more widely known.  I'll take this chance to try and popularize it.  First some notation.

Let $M=(E,r_M)$ be a matroid and let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint subsets of $E$.
We define the *local connectivity* between $A$ and $B$ to be

$\sqcap_M(A,B):=r_M(A)+r_M(B)-r_M(A \cup B)$.

We next define $\lambda_M(A):=\sqcap_M(A,E-A)$, and call $\lambda_M$ the *connectivity function* of $M$.  It is fairly straightforward to check that $\lambda_M$ is symmetric, submodular, invariant under duality, and monotone under taking minors.  Finally, we define

$\kappa_M(A,B) = \min(\lambda_M(X) : A \subseteq X \subseteq E-B)$.  It is easy to show that for any $C \subseteq E - (A \cup B)$, we have $\sqcap_{M / C} (A,B) \leq \kappa_M(A,B)$.  Tutte's linking theorem says that we can always find a $C$ that gives us equality.

**Tutte's Linking Theorem.** There exists $C \subseteq E - (A \cup B)$, such that 
$\sqcap_{M / C} (A,B) = \kappa_M(A,B)$.

The proof is not very difficult, so instead I'll just briefly say why this generalizes Menger's theorem for graphs.  The form of Menger's theorem that it generalizes is

**Menger's Theorem.**  Let $a$ and $b$ be non-adjacent vertices in a graph $G$.  Let $k$ be the size of a smallest vertex cut separating $a$ and $b$.  Then there exist $k$ internally vertex disjoint paths between $a$ and $b$.

*Proof (via Tutte's Linking Theorem)*.  Let $A$ and $B$ be the sets of edges incident to $a$ and $b$ respectively.  Note that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint since $a$ and $b$ are non-adjacent.  Let $k$ be the size of the smallest vertex cut separating $a$ and $b$.  Now just apply Tutte's Linking Theorem to $A$ and $B$ together with the following two observations:

1. $k = \kappa_{M(G)}(A,B)+1,$ and
2. there exists $n$ internally vertex disjoint paths between $a$ and $b$ if and only if there exists
   $C \subseteq E(G) - (A \cup B)$ such that $\sqcap_{M(G /C)}(A,B) \geq n-1$.

Comment: Thank you for this very nice answer! I did not know this theorem. Let me express it as min-mux formula
$$
\min_{A\subset X\subset B} r(X)+r(E\setminus X)-r(E)=\max_{C\subset E\setminus (A\cup B)} r(A\cup C)+r(B\cup C)-r(C)-r(A\cup B\cup C)
$$
and ask, wether is it the most general min-max principle for matroids, or it is a particular case of something even more general?

Comment: @Fedor: perhaps submodularity is hiding somewhere?

Comment: @Fedor: It is possible to view (an equivalent form of) Tutte's Linking Theorem as a special case of the Matroid Intersection Theorem, which is a min-max formula.  I believe this is the approach that the encyclopedia (Schrijver) takes.  See my answer to this [question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40005/generalizing-a-problem-to-make-it-easier/40017#40017) for a statement and application of matroid intersection.

Comment: @Tony: I do not see how to does it follow from the matroid intersection, or matroid union, or Rado transversal theorem or anything in such flavour. Would you please give a hint?

Comment: @Fedor: If C is a maximum size common independent set of M / A \B and M \A /B, then C in fact gives equality in the min-max formula that you wrote

Comment: @TonyHuynh Menger theorem also holds true for oriented graphs. Is there oriented matroids version of Tutte linking theorem (or, to start with, of matroid intersection theorem?)

Comment: @FedorPetrov To be honest, I do not know too much about oriented matroids.  The only theorem I know along these lines is a paper of Andreas Holmsen about the intersection of an oriented matroid with a matroid.  http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870815005149

Comment: @TonyHuynh Thank you, very interesting! But this is strange: Holmsen' theorem looks deep, with topological proof, while oriented Menger theorem does not essentially differ from the non-oriented, right?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, for graphs, oriented Menger is essentially the same as Menger.  But oriented Menger for graphs you can get from Menger for matroids (via Gammoids).  https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Gammoid

Comment: @TonyHuynh but how does gammoid help to prove Menger theorem? This was my original question:)

Comment: @FedorPetrov I see.  So you want a matroid proof of the directed version of Menger's Theorem?

Comment: @TonyHuynh yes, it would be nice to have a proof using gammoid