# Maximum of a series of integrals of Hermite functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

Given the function $$f(A) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \int_A \varphi_0\varphi_n \right)^2,$$ where $A$ is any measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and $\varphi_n$ is the $n$th Hermite function, I want to know for which sets $f$ attains its maximum.

I've already proven that $$f(A)\le \frac{1}{4}$$ for all $A$, and that $f(\mathbb{R}^+) = 1/4$. But it is crucial for my problem to find other sets that would also maximise $f$ or prove that none exists, and for doing that I am at a loss. Even finding local maxima would be interesting to me.

The proof I already obtained is somewhat long and very indirect, so I won't include it here; also, I'm very interested to see how a mathematician would approach this problem.

Comment: The Hermite functions are $\phi_n(x)={(-1)^n\over\sqrt{2^nn!\sqrt{\pi}}}e^{x^2/2}{\partial^n\over\partial x^n}(e^{-x^2})$.


Comment: You can also note that $\int_x^\infty \phi_0\phi_n={H_{n-1}(x)\over\sqrt{n!2^n}}{e^{-x^2}\over\sqrt\pi}$, which helps to reduce the set $A$ via endpoints. Here $H_n$ is the $n$th Hermite polynomial, via the physicists counting, so $H_1(x)=2x$.

Comment: Letting the set be $A=[-t,t]$, there is a local maximum somewhere around $t=1/2$, but it seems to be somewhat beneath it, and I don't know what the value is. This might be known, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your quantity as:
$$f(A)=\hbox{Tr}\left[ P_A|0\rangle\langle0|P_A(\mathbb{1}-|0\rangle\langle0|) \right],$$
where $P_A$ is the projection on A, and $|0\rangle\langle0|$ is the projection on $\varphi_0$.
Note that then you need only to investigate properties of the $\varphi_0$, not every Hermite function (as they form an orthonormal basis).

With the properties of Tr and projection operators you get
$$f(A)= \hbox{Tr}[|0\rangle\langle0|P_A|0\rangle\langle0|]-\hbox{Tr}[(|0\rangle\langle0|P_A|0\rangle\langle0|)^2]$$
$$=\lambda-\lambda^2.$$

So:

- indeed, $\max f(A)  = \frac{1}{4}$,
- $f(A)=\frac{1}{4}$ iff $\int_{A} \varphi_0^2(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}$.

Depending what you need the formula for, but if it is about the filtering of the higher-order modes, [here (sec. 6.)](http://www.springerlink.com/content/n57345p035262823/) is a numerical remark.

Comment: Very cool. Seems to be a good example of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40005/ as this works for any orthonormal basis, not just for the Hermite functions. Also there's nothing special with $|0\rangle$, any other vector works.

But I would make your expressions a bit simpler: first express $f$ as $$f(A) = \langle 0|P_A(1-|0\rangle \langle 0|)P_A|0\rangle$$, then by linearity $$f(A) = \langle 0|P_A|0\rangle - (\langle 0|P_A|0\rangle)^2$$

I need this formula to study violations of a Bell inequality in a quantum optical system. So, the reference is a bit related, but not much.

Comment: Actually, $f(A)=\int_A\phi_0^2 -\left(\int_A\phi_0^2\right)^2$ is just the Parseval identity. 

Comment: @Pietro: Could you clarify? By 'Perseval identity' I know $|\psi|_2=|U \psi|_2$ for unitary $U$ acting on a vector $\psi$ (especially when $U$ is the Fourier transform).

Comment: I think Pietro is referring to the identity $$\|x\|^2 = \sum_n |\langle x, \varphi_n\rangle|^2,$$ setting $x = \varphi_0$ and passing the term $|\langle \varphi_0, \varphi_0\rangle|^2$ from the rhs to the lhs. Doing the inner product with weight $P_A$, of course.

It is interesting to notice that the result is more general than I thought; however I prefer the direct proof.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshot saved on the Wayback Machine.

Comment: Reposting the link mentioned in a previous [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/166938) so that it appears in the "Linked" questions list: [Generalizing a problem to make it easier](https://mathoverflow.net/q/40005)