# How large do $r$-dimensional "Kasteleyn-Temperley-Fisher" numbers grow?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, asymptotics, entropy

I brought up a couple of combinatorial and number-theoretic items with [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258386/kasteleyns-formula-for-domino-tilings-generalized). Now, I shall inquire on growth estimates. Recall
$$K_r(n):=\prod_{\ell_1=1}^n\cdots\prod_{\ell_r=1}^n\left(
4\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi\ell_1}{2n+1}\right)+\cdots+4\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi\ell_r}{2n+1}\right)\right).$$

> **Question.** Fix $r\geq3$. Can you provide an asymptotic (at least of first order) for $K_r(n)$, as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

**Example.** $K_1(n)=1$. It's also known (K.T.F.) that $K_2(n)\sim e^{\frac{4G}{\pi}n^2}$ where $G=$ [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant).

Comment: Wasn't this answered [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/264751/asymptotics-for-generalized-kasteleyns-formula/264773#264773): $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^{-r}\log K_r(n)=2\log 2+C_r$, with $C_r$ some numerical coefficient given by an integral over the $r$-dimensional unit cube [$C_3=0.287095$, $C_4=0.613413$, $C_5=0.856191$, ...]